# In my my project when I installed django-filebrowser some conflicts happened, conflicts in style only not in any functions

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli, django-filebrowser, django-fluent

In my project I want to integrate fluent_dashborad for the admin interface, when I installed django-filebrowser some conflicts happened, conflicts in style only but not in any functionality.

this is my installed apps,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'fluent_dashboard',
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'admin_tools',
    'object_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.flash',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.teaser',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
    'ckeditor',
    'modeltranslation',
    'cms',
    'haystack',
    'cms_search',
    'export',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'endless_pagination',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'apps.cmsplugin_title',
    'apps.cmsplugins',
    'apps.newsletters',
    'apps.contactus',
    'apps.cmsplugin_gallery',
    'apps.inline_ordering',
    'apps.gallery',
    'apps.website_settings',
    'apps.career',
    'apps.general',  
    'captcha',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
)
```

When I comment grappelli and admin_tools. the fluent dashboard is working perfectly but the style conflicts are coming in file browser.

When I tried disabling the fluent dashboard and enabling grappelli and admin_tools, it works perfectly. but I want fluent_dashboard itself.

So either one of these will work alone but not together. How to make them work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grapelli and django-fluent-dashboard currently aren't compatible.

Grapelli already provides their own dashboard code. This was extracted into "django-admin-tools" to be usable outside grapelli. fluent-dashboard is built on top of that.

You can already use what grapelli provides, and take the useful bits from fluent-dashboard (e.g. the `IconAppList` class).

(p.s. a pull request to improve grapelli compatibility is welcome off course)